# Clickhouse-backup restore empty databases

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-backup

Trying to setup clickhouse-backup according to this manual https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup/blob/master/Examples.md#how-to-use-clickhouse-backup-in-kubernetes

All look good to me but when I decided to wipe & restore to test - restore doesn't work.

Remote look like this:

```
clickhouse-backup list
2022-09-05T14-28-31   73.71KiB    05/09/2022 14:29:03   remote      tar, regular
2022-09-05T23-47-29   541.83MiB   05/09/2022 23:48:46   remote      tar, regular
2022-09-06T20-43-43   52.16MiB    06/09/2022 20:44:15   remote      tar, regular
```

First 73.71KiB backup was made with wrong setup and was backing up only metadata (no full access to /var/lib/clickhouse).

Then I try this sequence of commands described in the same doc https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup/blob/master/Examples.md#restore

My clickhouse configuration shardsCount: 1, replicasCount: 5

So I connect to pods and do
All replicas

```
clickhouse-backup restore_remote --rm --schema 2022-09-05T23-47-29
clickhouse-backup delete local 2022-09-05T23-47-29
```

1st replica

```
clickhouse-backup restore_remote --rm 2022-09-05T23-47-29
clickhouse-backup delete local 2022-09-05T23-47-29
```

Then a number of warning like this arise:

```
2022/09/07 20:34:20.890442  info CREATE TABLE foo.bar (`project` String, `taskId` String, `addedAt` Nullable(DateTime('Europe/Copenhagen')), `metadata` String, `userId` String, `domain` String) ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{installation}/{cluster}/tables/{shard}/foo/bar', '{replica}') PARTITION BY project ORDER BY (domain, project) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
2022/09/07 20:34:21.016010  warn can't create table 'foo.bar': code: 253, message: Replica /clickhouse/clickhouse/app-staging/tables/0/foo/bar/replicas/chi-clickhouse-app-staging-0-2 already exists, will try again backup=2022-09-05T23-47-29 operation=restore
```

`clickhouse-backup tables` shows a number of 0B tables.

I'm not the person who created all the tables but I guess they worked fine before I started experimenting with backups. `clickhouse-backup` seem to be popular so it should work. Would be nice to know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what I was doing wrong. While experimenting a lot at some point I set `CLICKHOUSE_HOST` to CHI cluster service hostname referencing as load-balancer all replicas. When removing-creating databases it was done randomly on different replicas. `CLICKHOUSE_HOST` in my case always should be `localhost`. Working with zookeeper CLI helped a lot to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by „wipe“? Did you truncate the table, did you drop the table, or something else?

The error messages indicates that while the table might not exist in Clickhouse, the meta data still exists in Zookeeper. Zookeeper stores a set of meta data for replication purposes. So you could give it a try and, with the help of zkCli.sh, drop the node where the table resides in Zookeeper - you defined it when you created the table inside the ReplicatedMergeTree() statement.

Comment: Yeah, working with Zookeeper CLI helped to solve my issue.